# Como hacer submit en varias vistas parciales usando un único botón en ASP. NET MVC C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mi problema es que tengo varias vistas parciales y cada una maqueta un formulario lo que necesito es enviar los datos de todos los formularios en estas vistas al controlador con un solo botón submit si esta no es la mejor forma de hacer esto por favor de orientarme ya que soy nuevo en eso y no estoy seguro de que esta sea la mejor manera de hacerlo!

Esta es la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta vista que se encarga de llamar tanta vistas parciales _Evaluacion como Item en el modelo.

```
@model IEnumerable<Academia.Models.Item>


<h2>Encuesta</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    @Html.Action("_Evaluacion", "Cursos", new { ItemID = item.ItemID })

}


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-offset-2">
        <input name="Guardar" type="button" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta es la vista parcial `_Evaluacion` la cual se encarga de maquetar un formulario con la cantidad de campos necesarios para cada Item:

```
@model Academia.ViewModels.EvaluacionViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}




  @using (Html.BeginForm("GuardarEvaluacion", "Cursos", FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

             <table>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    <h3>@item.Detalle</h3>
                    <div>
                        <textarea hidden name="Evaluaciones.Item">@item.ItemID</textarea>
                    </div>


                foreach (var item2 in Model.Respuestas)
                {
                        <input type="radio" unchecked="Uncheck" name="Evaluaciones.Respuesta" value="@item2.RespuestaID"> @item2.Detalle
                        <br>
                    }

                  }

                <br>

            </table>
     }
```

Y tengo esto en mi controlador:

```
public ActionResult GuardarEvaluacion(EvaluacionViewModel View)
    {
        Evaluacion Oevaluacion = new Evaluacion();

        Oevaluacion.Item = View.Evaluaciones.Item;
        Oevaluacion.respuesta = View.Evaluaciones.respuesta;

        db.Evaluacion.Add(Oevaluacion);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

El problema es que al hacer submit solo recibo el primer registro en mi controlador el cual corresponde a mi primera vista parcial perdiendo así los datos ingresados en las otras vistas parciales.
Como puedo enviar al controlador todas las respuestas seleccionadas en cada una de las vistas parciales usando solo un botón submit para esto?

Comment: ¿Qué te llevó a la decisión de usar vistas parciales para eso? Te diría casi con seguridad que tu problema surge debido a que las vistas parciales no son para esto

Answer (score 1):

Saca el `@Html.BeginForm` fuera del primer `@foreach`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Academia.Models.Item>

<h2>Encuesta</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("GuardarEvaluacion", "Cursos", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.Action("_Evaluacion", "Cursos", new { ItemID = item.ItemID })
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-offset-2">
            <input name="Guardar" type="button" value="Guardar" class="btn btn- success" />
       </div>
   </div>   
}
```

y luego **elimínalo** (el `@Html.BeginForm`) de la Vista parcial `_Evaluacion`:

---

**IMPORTANTE:**

Ahora en tu Controlador recibirás **todos los campos de las Vistas parciales** a la vez, así que deberás hacer los cambios necesarios en los **datos recibidos** en la Acción `GuardarEvaluacion(....)`.

Comment: Hey Rafita, hermano, ¿te gustaría participar conmigo en un webcast sobre ASP.net MVC para algún sábado de febrero-marzo?

Comment: @fredyfx Buenas, envíame algún ejemplo de lo que haces .. a ver si me animo, y recuerda el desfase horario. Si quieres podemos hablar o chatear por otro medio.. dime tu.

Comment: Pues, el año pasado hice este con el buen @gbianchi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqzVCY1jzXQ y de los "webcast oficialels" que hicimos con la comunidad de SOes, puedes verlos aquí: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg para comunicarnos, entra a la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol me encuentras seguido por esos lares, en Twitter me ubican rápidamente como "@fredyfx" :D

Comment: @fredyfx Ok.. Estamos en contacto amigo.. ;)

Comment: perfecto mi estimado, me avisas si te animas, veo tu colaboración bastante activa y siento que podría salir un buen evento online :D